# Lisp / Scheme : Progn vs And

Tags: scheme, lisp, evaluation

I'd like to know if I can substitute **progn** with **and** in situations which the function must evaluate a sequence of s-expressions.

Exemple comes from How To Design Programs (http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-9.html#node_thm_6.6.12)

*"Develop draw-and-clear-rectangle, which draws a rectangle, sleeps for a while, and then clears the rectangle."*

```
(define (draw-and-clear a-rectangle)
  (and (draw-solid-rect... )
       (sleep-for-a-while... )
       (clear-solid-rect... )))
```

As and's arguments are evaluated sequentially, is there any difference from using a progn/begin form ?

Comment: Most versions of AND in Lisp will stop when one of the subforms returns NIL. PROGN will always run all subforms,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read HtDP, however, I think they're using `and` instead of `begin` because some of the student languages do not provide `begin`.

In Scheme, the only false value is `#f`, and in particular, many "side-effecting" procedures return "an unspecified value"¹ which is invariably a true value, so you can effectively sequence them using `and`. This contrasts with Common Lisp, where side-effecting procedures usually return `nil`, which is a false value.

¹ Most Scheme implementations will return the same kind of unspecified value consistently: in Racket, it uses `(void)`, and in most other implementations that don't have `(void)`, it's whatever `(cond)` returns.

Comment: I don't think that's true for Common Lisp. Many functions with side effects return some kind of object...

Comment: @Rainer I don't mean linear-update functions (like `nreverse`), I'm talking about things like `setf` that's used purely for side effects.

Comment: That's strange. SETF in Common Lisp returns the multiple values of the last form...

Comment: Whoops, I should have had CLHS in front of me before writing these sorts of comments. :-)

Comment: One sees code like this `(let ((obj ...)) ... (foo (setf obj (make-bar :baz 42))) ... obj ...)`. That requires SETF to return something useful...

Answer (score 4):

`progn` will evaluate each of its S-expressions in sequence. `and` will not evaluate any after the first one that returns false (`#f` in Scheme or `nil` in Common Lisp). That sort of behavior is called the [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of boolean operators.

(Likewise, `or` will not evaluate any S-expression after the first that returns a true value.)